# ListView header

Tags: java, android

i create a header layout (xml file) that take whole one screen layout...

and i also created a listView and i added this header_layout to the listView:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
final View headerL = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
swipeListView.addHeaderView(headerL, null, false);
```

the listview is under the header layout.

However, the header is stretched on the whole page and when i try to scroll the header ( to scroll down that i will see the listView), it doesnt scroll down..

the headerView is not scrollable and therefore i cant reach the listView...

is there another implementation to do it? or make the header to be scrollable?

the listView is not empty and i checked it via debug mode

Also, if i remove the headerView from the listView (My page containes only listView, without header) it show me the listView well

thanks alot

Comment: You should probably describe the problem in the heading of your post instead of being so general.

Comment: Please post your layout xml and some more detail of what you want to implement

Comment: hi, i dont have a spesific layout xml..i have a listView with header layout and i have the problem that i described above, if i was not clear, please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wish the header to be scrollable just like the other views, you can implement the method [BaseAdapter.getItemViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) , so that for the first position, it would return the type of the header, and for the rest, the type of the normal types.

then, in the getView method, you would check which type to inflate/re-use , and fill it with the needed data when needed.

example:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(final int position) 
  {
  return position==0?0:1;
  }

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) 
  {
  int rowType=getItemViewType(position);
  if(rowType==0)
    {
    //handle a header (don't forget to use convertView)
    }
  else 
    {
    //handle a simple row (don't forget to use convertView and use the correct item)
    }
  }
```

for more tips regarding listView, check out the "[the world of listview](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)" lecture.

Comment: did you mean getView method? because when i extends the BaseAdapter class, i can override the getView method and not the getItemViewType... Also, i didnt understand what is the type that i need to return ?  thanks alot :)

Comment: getItemViewType is public so you can override it. about the return type, you decide which is what. for example, for the header return 0, and for regular rows return 1 .it's just for your convenience, just like other methods there that you can extend (lke getItem and getItemId). please check out the lecture. it might help you out.

Comment: i have implemented  getItemViewType as you said above in my getview but it is not working , still i'm not able to scroll from Header , please anyone guides me?

Comment: @user12345 Can you show the code? Maybe make a new question thread and show me a link to it?

Comment: no my issue is same as above i'll send you link to my issue , i'm using swipleable list view
https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/issues/171

Comment: i'm using Custom ArrayAdapter with  swipleable list view , your above solution did not work for me ?

Comment: Hi, i 've posted my Custom ArrayAdapter Code here https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/issues/171

Comment: @user12345 The problem is that you didn't implement the method "getItemViewType" as I've written that you need to do, so it will always return you the same value. You need to implement it and later use it in getView. if only the first item is the header, for example, make it return 0 for position 0 , and 1 for the rest. Then, in the getView, call getItemViewType and create/re-use the correct view according to the value you get from it : if it's 0, create/re-use the header, otherwise, create/re-use a normal row. I really suggest you to watch the Google-IO lecture.

Comment: @user12345 I've updated the answer to be with some code.

Answer (score 0):

a header view is not supposed to be scrollable because it is the heading of the listview.. meaning it should always be shown above the listview, regardless of the position of the list. Which is working as designed...Right now you cannot use a listview header for what you want.

You need to create your own listview and allow the header view to be scrollable within the bounds of the scroll view.

Keep in mind that if there header is scrollable that's going to be confusing design. I recommend stick with the standards.

Comment: hi, thanks for answer, how can i create my own listView with header?  i want to create something like in the facebook app, i will have a profilepicture and some button and when i scroll them down i will have a listView with items..something like this, can you give me an example what do you mean? i dont want that the header will be static, i want the header will disappear with i scroll to the listview... thanks alot

Comment: please help me, if you know :)